# Measurement protocol - Cookie

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics, measurement-protocol

Does Measurement protocol create cookie when request is sent to google analytics ? 
If so what is the name of cookie, its location . Does it track users based on IP address ?

Because i do not see any _ga cookie or _utma etc cookies when request are sent to google analytics using measurement protocol.
I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

The measurement protocol is just that, a protocol (a specification how to do things). If and how cookies are set depends on your implementation - for example Universal Analytics is built on top of the measurement protocol and sets a _ga cookie to persist the user id. However the use of cookies is not specified by the protocol, just that you need to pass a user id (which is used to track users, IP is just used for location information).

Comment: Eike, do you have any complex overview of MP - how CID and UID is used, best practices, limitations etc.? Any articles, slide decks? Thanks!